# Fix Boot on Windows 11 after removing a data SSD

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, ssd

I had Windows 10 installed on a M.2, then I bought a new M.2 and installed Windows 11. Everything was fine, except I had to choose which OS I want to boot from.

Then I remove my old M.2 with Windows 10 and the system not boot anymore. I've tried to run the repair console from an USB drive and did:

```
> bootsec /fixmbr
The operation completed successfully.
> bootsec /fixboot
The operation completed successfully
> bootsec /rebuildbcd
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully
```

This seem not to work :( So I ran `diskpart`:

```
diskpart> select disk 0

diskpart> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label       Fs    Type       Size     Status
  ----------  ---  ----------  ----  ---------  -------  -------
* Volume 0                     NTFS  Partition  1863 GB  Healthy
  Volume 1     C   Windows 11  NTFS  Removable    14 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2     D   UEFI_NTFS   FAT   Removable   512 KB  Healthy

diskpart> list partition
  
  Partition ###  Type             Size   Offset
  -------------  ------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Reserved        16 MB  1024 KB
* Partition 2    Primary       1863 GB    17 MB
```

It seems I don't have any UEFI partition on my Volume 0. Would it be possible to make this volume boot without reinstalling Windows?

In other words is it possible to resize Volume 0 and create a UEFI_NTFS partition and a MBR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First boot with any third party bootable utility packages like Hiren Boot CD. Boot from the HBCD drive and shrink the partition 0. Restart the system.

Boot now with windows 10 DVD. press shift+F10 on first screen. This will come up with command prompt. At command prompt run these commands.

diskpart

select disk 0 (here 0 assumed to be the drive where you shrunk the partition)

create partition efi

format quick fs=fat32

list volume
(write down your windows volume. Here I consider it as X)

exit   (exit from diskpart)

bcdboot X:\windows

exit

Now restart your system and check it.

Comment: Thank you @A.V.M. Computers, it was very helpful. My feedback after successfully repairing my W11 installation :
diskpart can be used to shrink the partition (therefore the full procedure can be done using the installation disk)
You should specify the size of the efi partition (create partition efi size=100) otherwise it may be created using all the free space on the disk and you won't be able to format it in FAT32. If you did so, just delete the partition and recreate it with the correct size (you may have to use the OVERRIDE parameter to force deleting the partition)